# Django ModelForm Boolean Field giving None when True

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    fries_with_that = models.BooleanField()
```

forms.py:

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (
            'fries_with_that',
        )
```

This works fine, and gives me drop-down with 'unknown', 'yes' and 'no' as choices. But I really want a checkbox. So I added:

### Edit

```
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            self.fields['fries_with_that'].widget = forms.CheckboxInput()
```

Now I get a checkbox but when checked, the form returns a value of `None`. Why is this?

### Edit

views.py:

```
form = MyModelForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    # UPDATE PROJECT
    updated = MyModel.objects.filter(
        project_id=project_id
    ).update(**form.cleaned_data)
    if updated == 0:
        project = form.save()
```

Comment: how are you retriving it in the view ?

Comment: Added view code. Also, I see from the docs that the default for a `BooleanField` should be a checkbox. Why do I get a drop-down?

Comment: Are you using a `NullBooleanField`? They default to a select box with unknown, yes, and no as the options.

Comment: You added this line where? `self.fields['fries_with_that'].widget = forms.CheckboxInput()`

Comment: in `__init__` override. Sorry, should have clarified that.

Comment: I am definitely using a `BooleanField`, not `NullBooleanField`.

Comment: Do some testing, inside the `if is_valid():` do. `raise Excepction(cleaned_data['fries_with_that'])` to see the actual value the form is taking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):

    fries_with_that = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput, default=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (
            'fries_with_that',
        )
```

actually, this should render the checkbox.

```
fries_with_that = forms.BooleanField()
```

Comment: Ok, that got it. But why do I need to declare Boolean here? Isn't it  a given if the model field is a `BooleanField`?

Comment: It would be `None` by default if your `BooleanField` in the models is nullable.

Comment: But in my models I have just `fries_with_that = models.BooleanField()`. Nothing more.

Comment: There is no default specified. Hence it takes it as `None`. If you specify a `default` it would default to that.